# Can't Drag'n'Drop files in VirtualBox from guest

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, drag-and-drop

I cannot drag & drop files from my guest system to my host one.
My host is Windows 7.  The guest is Ubuntu 12.04.3. 
I can drag & drop files from host to guest but not other way around.
My Drag'n'Drop is enabled Bidirectional.
Guest Additions are installed.

Can you tell me what I'm missing in my setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI: This question has already been asked and answered (several times)...

Nevertheless...

Drag and Drop is not yet implemented to work guest to host. In addition, AFAIK Drag and Drop is still expermental and thus not stable.

I do not know, why they included the "bidirectional" checkbox while that is not implemented, however... ;)

Comment: the "bidirectional" checkbox is added for copy content from the clipboard to the VM/host.